# Umbraco get node by ID in Razor

Tags: razor, umbraco

I am trying to get a node by it's ID through a Razor script, but I keep getting this error:

> error CS0118: 'umbraco.MacroEngines.BaseContext.Node' is a 'property'
>   but is used like a 'type'

Here is my code:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@{
var node = new Node(Parameter.newsnode);
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something very basic here, just can't seem to figure it out.
Umbraco 4.11.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was as simple as including Umbraco.NodeFactory

```
@using umbraco.NodeFactory
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I generally do this:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext
@{
  // Get some default node id if this is null or empty
  var newsNodeId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(Parameter.newsnode) ? "1022" : Parameter.newsnode;

  // Get the node using this helper method on DynamicNode
  var newsNode = @Model.NodeById(newsNodeId);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it by simpler to just write
`var newsNodeId = Parameter.newsnode ?? "1022";`?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't seen that syntax.  Where are the docs for the ?? operator?  Does it check for String.NullOrEmpty()?  Is it exactly equivalent?

Comment: It's called the Coalesce-operator. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: Cool! I've used something like that in SQL, but didn't know that existed in .NET.  Question: does it return true if the string is empty ("" <--- this is != null)?  In which case that would throw an error in Razor with that NodeById() method.

Comment: You could use it like this `Parameter.newsnode.SiteNumber.NullIfEmpty() ?? "1022"`, then you get what you ask for :)
I like it since it increases the readability of the code (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

There is this simple function :

```
@{
    var node = @Library.NodeById(Model.Id);
}
```

@* OR *@

```
@{
    var node = @Library.NodeById(1250);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are programming something for Umbraco and fast want to know the availble options for your Razor code you could use the cheatSheet: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/razor-dynamicnode-cheat-sheet. Also read this documentation: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/code-snippets/razor-snippets